# Do I Need to Add android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE for Firebase Analytics?

Tags: android, flutter, crashlytics, firebase-analytics, firebase-performance

Do I need to add android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE for Firebase Analytics?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>` view network connections,Which mean allows the app to view information about network connections such as which networks exist and are connected.

Here is the list of all permissions you can use:
https://gist.github.com/Watsonboy1989/fa01a6869d82062c770e137107693744